# Number of hypotheses from a decision tree?

Tags: decision-tree

I apologize for asking this question on here but I am confused on an idea about the number of hypotheses that a decision tree represents. It is one hypothesis or is it multiple hypotheses?

Answer (score 0):

No worries!

> [Decision Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) is a decision support tool which model of decisions and their consequences. [Decision Tree Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) produces a predictive model which maps observations from about an item (i.e. price) to item's target value (i.e. purchase or not, the price of house).

Each tree represent a single hypothesis which classifies or regresses examples.